# How to check if a macro can be followed by a newline

Tags: line-breaking, package-writing

I'm trying to create a class that allows you to define a name using

```
\name{Whatever}
```

This is defined as

```
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\gsy@name{#1}}
```

Whatever is passed to this is used in the header, and is followed by `\\`
and more content:

```
\rhead{\gsy@name\\More stuff on the next line}
```

Unfortunately, the whole thing breaks when someone passes nothing or a space
to `\name`:

```
\name{   }
```

This results in the `\\` trying to end a blank line, and the whole thing
refusing to compile.

Is there any way I can detect if something that can't be followed by `\\` is
passed to my macro?

Comment: Suggesting `\rhead{\gsy@name~\\More stuff on the next line}` feels like handing out free guns to kids.

Comment: Assuming the stuff in the name should in principle always be there, and you're just worried about catching the error, put the stuff in the header into a `tabular`:  `\rhead{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}\gsy@name\\Some more text\end{tabular}}`. This will leave a blank line in the header if the name is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\notblank{\gsy@name}{stuff with \\}{empty or other stuff}` with an `\expandafter` of `\gsy@name` should work. It tests whether the first argument is empty (blank/space/white space) or not.

Please not that `fancyhdr` might complain about the `\headheight` value

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\gsy@name{#1}}
\rhead{\expandafter\notblank\expandafter{\gsy@name}{\gsy@name\\More stuff on the next line}{}}

\makeatother
%\name{Stuff }
\name{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
Foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: one note: the displayed text on a page won't always correspond to the last use of `\name{}` on that page; try `\foreach \i in {1,...,100} { \name{\i}Paragraph \i\par }` (and `\usepackage{tikz}`) to see this in effect. The reason is that by the time LaTeX decides to output a page, it has already processed some content that will go on the next page.

Comment: @wrtlprnft: Yes, but that's not the question. The question was about `empty` arguments

Comment: I know, but I figured I'd mention this to avoid any suprises (also, I'm not sure how one would solve this problem). I of course didn't want to suggest that you didn't answer the question.

Comment: Why did you use `\edef` instead of `\def`?  What's the difference?  Should I have been using `\edef`?

Comment: @g.rocket: You can use `\def` too. I thought I would need to pre-expand (`\expanded def`), but that's not the case. I'll change to `\def`.